# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I am writing a script which has command to execute as below:

```
cat /abc | grep -v ^# | grep -i root  | sed -e '\''s/"//g'\'' | awk '\''{print $2}'\''
```

When running the script on SunOS, i am getting below error:

```
test: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
test: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Tried with different option.. but no luck.

Need somebody help me identify what is missing in the above command.

Comment: What are you trying to do? In other word, what are your input and output? I have a feeling you can accomplish your task with only awk.

Answer (score 2):

what are those escapes ?!

```
cat /abc | grep -v '^#' | grep -i root | sed -e '\''s/"//g'\'' | awk '\''{print $2}'\''
                                                 ^         ^          ^             ^
```

Your problem is there:

```
sed -e '\''s/"//g'\''
             ^ unmatched
```

Comment: Is it that the double quote in the expression is causing this error?

Comment: I tried with following:

cat /abc | grep -v ^# | grep -i root | sed -e \'s/\"//g\' | awk \'{print $2}\' 

the o/p is:
bash-2.05# bash -x -v test
cat /abc | grep -v ^# | grep -i root  | sed -e \'s/\"//g\' | awk \'{print $2}\'
+ cat /
+ grep -v '^#'
+ grep -i root
+ sed -e ''\''s/"//g'\'''
Unrecognized command: 's/"//g'
+ awk ''\''{print' '}'\'''
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: How do i escape single quote in the script?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you don't want or need a single quote in the script.  It would help if you could explain what you are trying to do (edit the question to explain).

Comment: okay .. let me explain in detail:
i have a program that executes many shell commands remotely on the Unix box. The above command is one of them. Before executing any command the single quote is replced by '\'' (single backslash single single). Same is happening with my command. the execution of this command fails with error "syntax error: `end of file' unexpected".
The original command looks like:
cat <filename> | | grep -v ^# | grep -i root | sed -e 's/\"//g' | awk '{print $2}'

I do not wish to touch the single quote replacement part. How can i make the command working with that.

Comment: This is working perfectly for Linux.. but on Solaris, it errors

Comment: Something substitutes `'\''` for every single quote, and you don't want that to stop happening?  Sorry pal, I don't think it can fly.

Comment: 1. Given 'let me explain in detail', your  question is incomplete and missing important info. Consider editing your Q to give all the info we need to help solve it. 2. Are you trying to pass a full shell script 'thru-the-wire' to a remote machine? It's possible, but you'll run into  problems like you have described. 3. If it's working on Linux but not Solaris, then what are the differences? 4. You realize that Linux /bin/sh=/bin/bash, and Solaris /bin/sh=bourneShell? That could contrib to this issue. 5. Uuse `set -vx` to see(sortOf) how strs are parsed/evaluated/broken on spaces. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The quoting is all wrong.  Why do you use single quote, backslash, single quote, single quote,and always in that order?  Regardless, you have an unquoted double quote, so the shell expects you to add a closing quote for the quoted string which starts with that opening double quote.

As a matter of style, you should also lose the [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html), and think about how to simplify your script.  At least:

```
grep -v ^# /abc | grep -i root | sed -e 's/"//g' | awk '{print $2}'
```

... but in practice

```
awk '/^#/ { next } /[Rr][Oo][Oo][Tt]/ { gsub ("\"",""); print $2 }' /abc
```

Because some of the characters in the `awk` and `sed` scripts have a special meaning to the shell, we put them in single quotes.  If you need to have single quotes in a script, you need to double quote them; a frequent pattern is to have a string in single quotes adjacent to a string in double quotes, like this: `echo '"'"'"`.  This echos `"` (quoted in single quotes) immediately followed by `'` (quoted in double quotes).

**Edit** Updated analysis of quoting problem; added code example; corrected code example.  Final edit corrects quoting of `gsub` in awk script, and adds a small discussion of quoting.

Comment: it's not a double quote `"`, it's just two single quotes side by side ('' -> `''`). It makes no sense.

Comment: sed -e 's/"//g' in this, the single quotes are escaped using \, however the backslash is enclosed in single quote ..

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter I noticed and edited my response before I saw your comment.

Comment: @Mrun: I'm sorry, I don't understand your remark.  Sed doesn't want or need quotes, the only quotes you need are so that the shell doesn't substitute anything in the `sed` script.  You should probably read some or all of http://www.google.com/search?q=shell+quoting+tutorial

Comment: Yes. Sed do not require quotes. I just wanted to know, if they are used, how to escape them. Similarly for awk, how the single quotes can be escaped?

Comment: `echo "'"` echos a single quote.  `echo '"'` echos a double quote.  You can mix these, so `echo '"'"'"` echos a double quote (quoted in single quotes) immediately adjacent to a single quote (quoted in double quotes).  Again, read up on shell quoting.

Comment: The regex `/[Rr][Oo][Oo][Tt]/` is a bit ugly, the workarounds are not really shorter or more elegant.  `gawk` has the `IGNORECASE` option which might be more pleasing to the eye.  You could also say `lowercase($0) ~ /root/`